# any problems with Firths Logit model (to deal with separation)

Tags: regression, logistic, stata, separation

I am performing a Logit Model on binary variable SALE, when running on stata some of my explanatory variables were dropped as they were "perfect predictors". after some reading i believe the problem to be that of separation. some authors propose Firths method to deal with this. I can install the stata extension and run the tests again no problem but i want to know:

1. will this work for a relatively small dataset (n=207)?
2. are there any downsides to this approach? (bias or overstatement of errors, anything like that)

Comment: No time to provide an elaborate response, but Greenland recommends log-F(1,1) prior instead of Firth's bias correction method. And you can implement it by simply modifying your data, adding a few rows of data to the data before analysis. See http://andrewgelman.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Greenland-Mansournia.Firth-and-stronger-penalization.25June2014.pdf . Firth's method can actually lead to coefficients larger than the ML estimate in certain situations.

Answer (score 0):

Partially answered in comments:

> No time to provide an elaborate response, but Greenland recommends log-F(1,1) prior instead of Firth's bias correction method. And you can implement it by simply modifying your data, adding a few rows of data to the data before analysis. See http://andrewgelman.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Greenland-Mansournia.Firth-and-stronger-penalization.25June2014.pdf . Firth's method can actually lead to coefficients larger than the ML estimate in certain situations.    –
> Heteroskedastic Jim